# on_reaction_add doesn't trigger - Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have been looking online for answers to why this code doesn't ever trigger.

```
async def on_reaction_add(reaction):
print(reaction.emoji.name)
channel = await client.get_channel(reaction.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(reaction.message_id)
print(channel)
print(message)
```

I have been looking at some stack overflow questions and wasn't able to track down the answer. I have tried changing on_reaction_add to on_raw_reaction_add. I am new to this stuff, thanks for even thinking about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_reaction_add` takes two parameters, `reaction` and `user`. you need both for it to work, even though you might not need both for your purpose. You can read more on it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add).

```py
@client.event # Or bot event, depending on your code
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message     # Gives you the message object
    channel = message.channel      # Gives you the channel
    message_text = message.content # Gives you the text in the message
    print(channel)
    print(message_text)
```

`on_reaction_add` works only if the message is in the bots internal cache. that means if the message is old, or if the bot resets, the event wont trigger for that message. That's where `on_raw_reaction_add` comes in. it takes payload as a parameter, and the payload includes parameters such as user_id, message_id etc. You can read more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent).

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    channel_id = payload.channel_id
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    print(message.content)
    print(payload.emoji)
```

And in case you haven't set the right intents, have a look at [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents)

Comment: thanks, I'll be using on_raw_reaction_add

Comment: @MaximumG9 I've added an example on `on_raw_reaction_add` If the answer helped you, or solved your problem. you can "accept" an answer to mark the question as solved.